# How to get Heliocentric positions from pyswisseph or kerykeion library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using kerykeion library to get aspect but i think it get aspect using Geocenteric position is there any way to get Heliocenteric position.

kerykeion internally uses pyswisseph  and i can see there is Flag available but not sure how to use that

Flag is

```
FLG_HELCTR
```

I can see it supports changing observer positions as listed on the site about the test program for Swiss Ephemeris:

https://www.astro.com/cgi/swetest.cgi?arg=-h&p=0

You can pass Option

```
-hel
```

Any help would be really appreciated to get Heliocentric position using either library

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* That's software with priority rather for [astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology), then [astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomy), though Swiss Ephemeris admittedly seems to be a solid library.

---

For `pyswisseph` (Swiss Ephemeris) see its [documentation](https://astrorigin.com/pyswisseph/pydoc/index.html). There you will find the function

> **`orbit_max_min_true_distance(...)`**
>
> Calculate the maximum possible distance, the minimum possible distance, and the current true distance of planet, the EMB, or an asteroid.
>
> **:Args: float tjdet, int planet, int flags**
>
> - tjdet: input time, Julian day number, Ephemeris Time
> - planet: identifier of planet or object
> - flags: bit flags indicating what computation is wanted:
>
>   - ephemeris flag
>   - optional heliocentric flag **FLG_HELIOCTR**
>
> **:Return: float max_dist, float min_dist, float true_dist**
>
> - max_dist: maximum distance
> - min_dist: minimum_distance
> - true_dist: true distance

Also see `helio_cross(...)` and `helio_cross_ut(...)`.

You might want to stick rather with Swiss Ephemeris than Kerykeion. Latter uses the first anyway, as you noted, and SE is a kind of standard in the area of astrological software, and is even listed by the Smithsonian Astrophysical Center in the category of [Astronomical Software on the Web](http://tdc-www.harvard.edu/astro.software.html)